# XmlPullParser read InputSource

Tags: java, xml, xmlpullparser

I know how to create `InputSource` out of `Reader` but how to do it the other way around?

I'm capturing `org.xml.sax.InputSource` and now want to feed it into `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser`. That one has few setInput methods but these only accept `Reader` or `InputStream` as an argument. What would be the best way to convert `InputSource` into one of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me

```
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(is.getCharacterStream());
```

Where "is" is InputSource